Change CultureInfo within an async function in C#
I am currently working on a backend for an API that is used by international applications (several languages).
Currently I am going through Localization processes for my application. Because I have everything asynchrounous, and those not always start a new thread, I doubt that
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(CultureInfoString)
will do its job.
The thing is, I want to return everything in the language the user has set. How would I go about that?
I already tried setting the Thread Culture Information, but it will bug around when two async functions are called almost concurrently.
I also tried setting it with an IDisposable and using()

Is there any specific issue that you have noticed or are you asking us if setting the current thread's CurrentCulture could cause issues if used in an async context? Btw, it's not clear what "setting it with an IDisposable and using()" means.

"I want to return everything in the language the user has set" Where did the user has set the language? What kind of application is it at all? If it's a web application, why do you change the server's culture? Use the CultureInfo instance wherever you need to provide culture specific data(parsing DateTimes and so on).

The language was set in the API Endpoint. The user can choose any language via the language code (en, de, ...)

" The user can choose any language via the language code" what kind of data do you need localized? Plain Text? Date/Time/Number Formats? As-is it sounds like a problem you'd only have at the periphery? That is: "Translation" or "Localization" could be the very last step and done explicitly using overlaods / lookups that take a language code / culture code without actually setting any thread culture?

Have you tried it? The doc says The culture used by the current thread and task-based asynchronous operations.

yeah, it kinda works when there are not too many request.

If you are using ASP.NET Core, you are going to want to look at the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization package.
If you are using some other server framework, you will want to set the culture in whatever request context that framework provides.
Either way, you are not going to want to set the Thread.CurrentCulture property.
